# CanBuildFrom not found when invoked implicitly

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Consider the following REPL session:

```
@ def test[C[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]) = cbf()
defined function test

@ test[List]
res32: collection.mutable.Builder[Int, List[Int]] = ListBuffer()

@ def test[C[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]] = implicitly[CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]]
cmd33.sc:1: Cannot construct a collection of type C[Int] with elements of type Int based on a collection of type C[Int].
def test[C[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]] = implicitly[CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]]
                                                 ^
Compilation Failed
```

The first definition of `test` function compiles and works, while the second one doesn't compile. The only difference between them is the way how the instance of `CanBuildFrom` is obtained. In first case it's declared as implicit parameter, requiring the compiler to find one. In second case it's invoked via `implicitly` function, which, in theory, should behave the same in terms of implicit search scope. What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `implicitly` (in `Predef`) is:

```
def implicitly[A](implicit ev: A): A = A
```

It simply makes explicit to you an implicit already *in scope* (**at the use site**).

Now when you write this:

```
import collection.generic.CanBuildFrom

def test[C[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]]
  (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]) = ???
```

You are asking the caller to *provide* an implicit (**at the call site**).

When you write

```
def test[C[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]] = 
  implicitly[CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]]
```

You are asking the compiler with the call `implicitly` to look-up an implicit *already in scope*. **But you are not having any implicit of the given type in scope!** So the two definitions of `test` are doing something entirely different.

You use `implicitly` normally to get hold of an implicit to which you don't have the name, because it was specified using the context-bounds or type-class notation, like `def test[A: TypeClass]`. You cannot use that notation here because `CanBuildFrom` has three type parameters and not one. So you cannot do much with `implicitly` here.

You could use `implicitly` with your first case:

```
def test[C[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]]
  (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]) = {

  implicit val onceAgain = implicitly[CanBuildFrom[C[Int], Int, C[Int]]]
  assert(onceAgain == cbf)
}
```

But then you already know that you have that implicit with name `cbf`...

---

Note that you can get hold of an implicit `CanBuildFrom` for a known collection type:

```
implicitly[CanBuildFrom[List[Int], Int, List[Int]]]  // works!
```

But this doesn't work if your collection type (`C[X]`) is abstract.

Comment: But what is the difference between implicit scopes in these 2 situations? As I said, I did this in REPL, so in the first case a generic `CanBuildFrom` was found (in Predef, I suppose) when I called the function. This means, there's a suitable implicit instance of `CanBuildFrom` in the scope. Why the same one can't be used when defining a standalone function in REPL?

Comment: In one case you have a concrete type, e.g. `List`, in the other you have an abstract type parameter `C[_]`. Implicit resolution will look, among others, at the companion object of the type class (`CanBuildFrom`) and of its type parameters (e.g. here `List` - where it finds the type class instance!), but obviously cannot resolve an abstract type.

Comment: Right, now it makes sense.

Comment: Also see here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html ("Implicit scope of type arguments")